# Input string was not in a correct format when convert string to double

Tags: c#, if-statement, visual-studio-2013

I am a beginner using c#. I'm trying to code using if else statement in `c#` . When I run the program, this error message appear. It appears along the line `double x = Convert.ToDouble("XValue");`. I was trying to convert the string X value to double to match with my variable x.

```
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        connectDB();
        OpenConnection();


        MySqlCommand command = c.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM gazecoords INNER JOIN gazeperiod ON gazecoords.gazeID = gazeperiod.gazeID INNER JOIN trialImage on gazeperiod.imageID = trialImage.imageID INNER JOIN areacoords on trialImage.imageID = areacoords.trialImageID;";
        try
        {
            c.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader["imageID"].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(reader["topLeftX"].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(reader["topRightX"].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(reader["topLeftY"].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(reader["bottomLeftY"].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(reader["XValue"].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(reader["YValue"].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(reader["in"].ToString());

            while (reader.Read())
            {

                double x = Convert.ToDouble("XValue");
                double y = Convert.ToDouble("YValue");
               List <int> image = new List<int>(Convert.ToInt32("imageID"));
               // int coordsID = Convert.ToInt32("coordsID");
                double topLeftX = Convert.ToDouble("topLeftX");
                double topRightX = Convert.ToDouble("topRightX");
                double topLeftY = Convert.ToDouble("topLeftY");
                double bottomLeftY = Convert.ToDouble("bottomLeftY");
                int inside = Convert.ToInt32("in");
                inside = 0;

                foreach (int coordsID in image)
                {
                    if (x > topLeftX && x < topRightX && y > topLeftY && y < bottomLeftY)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("The value inside are the area is {0}", inside + 1);
                    }
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("0");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Oh come on. You didn't realize you try to parse `"XValue"` string , not `reader["XValue"]` value?

Comment: Well, the `String` `"XValue"` doesn't represent any `Double`, right? However, `reader["XValue"]` may contain a `Double` value

Comment: How is the XValue stored? Doesn't MySQL have a "real" `double` type, so it must be stored as a `string`? If it has to be a `string`, what number format is it stored in, and which number format is your default (CurrentCulture/CurrentUICulture)?

Comment: XValue stored in mysql are something like 363.0809 and stored as varchar(45). I have no idea which data type in c# is the right one to use for varchar as I am totally new to c#

Comment: Btw. the code you posted does not match the screenshot! In the code, you say `Convert.ToDouble("XValue")` which, as everyone pointed out, is wrong, of course, but in the screenshot it seems like you're correctly using it as `Convert.ToDouble(reader["XValue"])`.

Comment: I made changes in the screenshot after everyone pointing out where it went wrong but the error still shows when I try to run it.

Comment: @SPP - `varchar` translates to `string`, but I'm pretty sure, MySQL has a [more appropriate](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/floating-point-types.html) type. If it is at all possible, I'd urge you to always use the most appropriate type instead of ["stringly" typing](http://neologisms.rice.edu/index.php?a=term&d=1&t=14876) it. The MySQL type "DOUBLE" should translate well to the C# type `double`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
double x = Convert.ToDouble(reader["XValue"]);
```

It was trying to convert string "XValue" to Double which is not possible but now it will convert value of `reader["XValue"]`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing `reader["XValue"]` to `double x = Convert.ToDouble("XValue");`

 `XValue` is a `string` which is causing error while converting to `double`.

Change it to

```
double x = Convert.ToDouble(reader["XValue"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, *XValue* is *null*:

```
double x = Convert.ToDouble(reader["XValue"] ?? 0);
```

Comment: XValue is not null. I am a beginner using c# so I am very lost. my Xvalue is something like 363.0809, etc.

Comment: @SPP If you are using visual studio, select `reader["XValue"]` and right click -> click on Quick Watch and check the value here in debug mode.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @JamieR, it answers the question if the value is null. It is possible that reader has more than one rows and it is crashing on one of the row value that contains null, that is why it is not convertible to double and format exception is being raised.